# Чем отличается параметр разбиения Gini от Entropy в алгоритмах на основе деревьем?

Tags: машинное-обучение

Если на собеседование спросят, чем отличается параметр разбиения Gini от Entropy в алгоритмах на основе деревьем, что ответить кроме формул?

Answer (score 0):

Это две метрики для выбора способа разбить дерево. Измерение индекса Джини - это вероятность того, что случайная выборка будет классифицирована неправильно, если мы случайным образом выберем класс в соответствии с распределением в ветке дерева.

Энтропия - это мера информации (точнее ее отсутствия). Вы рассчитываете прирост информации, делая разбиение. В этом энтропия отличается, это измерение того, как вы уменьшаете неопределенность относительно класса.

В вычислительном отношении энтропия более сложна, поскольку в ней используются логарифмы и, следовательно, расчет индекса Джини будет быстрее.
В уравнении энтропии используются логарифмы из-за многих полезных свойств. Основное преимущество - это дополнительные свойства ([подробнее](http://web.mit.edu/6.02/www/f2011/handouts/2.pdf))